# Riverpod : future provider is stuck on loading

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-hooks

**Describe the bug**
when executing the provider with `ref.read` or `ref.watch` the result is the same , it is stuck on the loading block , while testing the api in postman works fine , the funny thing is that the api call gets executed and whenever i print something inside it it appears in the console

**To Reproduce**
**in presentation layer**

```
onpressed:()=>ref
                                                  .read(getPatientProvider(
                                                      r.api_token))
                                                  .when(data: (data) {
                                                data.fold(
                                                    (l) => print(
                                                        "something wrong happened"),
                                                    (r) async {
                                                  print(r.id);
                                                  print("hello");
                                                  patient.value = patient.value
                                                      .copyWith(
                                                          name: r.name,
                                                          aliid: r.id,
                                                          appointments: r
                                                              .patient_appointments,
                                                          fcmtoken: token);
                                                  ref.read(docexist(r.id)).when(
                                                      loading: () =>
                                                          print("loading"),
                                                      error: (error, _) =>
                                                          print(error),
                                                      data: (data) async {
                                                        print("heloo");
                                                        if (data.isEmpty) {
                                                          print(
                                                              "data is not empty");
                                                        } else {
                                                          return print(
                                                              "logged in normally");
                                                        }
                                                      });
                                                });
                                              }, error: (error, _) {
                                                print(error);
                                              }, loading: () {
                                                print("object");
                                              })
```

**Provider with riverpod generator**

```
@riverpod
Future<Either<ApiFailures, dynamic>> getPatient(
    GetPatientRef ref, String token) async {
  final patientProvider = ref.watch(patientRepositoryProvider);
  return patientProvider.getInfo(token);
}
```

**infrastructure layer**

```
@override
  Future<Either<ApiFailures, dynamic>> getInfo(String token) {
    var dio = Dio();
    final result = TaskEither<ApiFailures, PatientModel>(() async {
      try {
        final response = await dio.get(
            "https://xxxxxxxx/GetInfo?api_token=$token");
        if (response.data == null) {
          return const Left(ApiFailures.notfound());
        } else {
          PatientModel patientModel =
              PatientModel.fromJson(response.data["User"]);
          return Right(patientModel);
        }
      } catch (err, st) {
        final message = 'error ${err.runtimeType}]';

        if (kDebugMode) log(message, error: err, stackTrace: st);

        if (err is DioError) {
          return Left(ApiFailures.fromDioError(error: err));
        }
        return const Left(ApiFailures.internalError());
      }
    });
    return result.map((r) => r).run();
  }
```

**Expected behavior**
it should get the data as always

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `when` inside a click handler such as `onPressed` as you did does not make sense.

"when" does not wait for the future to complete. It executes immediately based on the current status of the future.
Considering that when you call it, you just triggered the future, then the future at that time will always be in a loading state.

What you want is something like `async`/`await`, where you can wait until the completion of your future.

You could do that with:

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  final value = await ref.read(provider.future);
}
```

Comment: thanks alot remi , sorry for asking here and on github